# Windows API Console Lock

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a simple, thread-safe console wrapper for Windows in C++. Looking at the API though, I don't see any functions for locking/unlocking access to the console. For memory, there is [HeapLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [HeapUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Do such functions exist for the console, or would I have to create my own mutex?

Edit:

As shown in the comments below, the console wrapper is to control access to the console. The lock is needed so that when a thread performs a compound operation on the console (for example, changing the console color, writing several messages, and then restoring the color), no other thread would be able to modify the console or write to it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by locking access to the console?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *console wrapper*?

Comment: @Sean As in locking the access, and performing multiple console operations to ensure no other thread modifies/writes to the console between them.

Comment: @AlexK. A class that controls access to the standard output for logging purposes.

Comment: There is no Console API function that will lock the console so that it can only be used by a single thread. If you want to do that kind of thing, you'll have to implement it with your own Mutex or similar, and even that won't really "lock" the console. It'll just be like any other Mutex: a convention that threads agree to abide by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should lock access to your functions that is responsible for logging. Like following code:

```
std::mutex mforlog;
void Log(std::string s) {
     std::unique_lock<mutex> lock{mforlog};
     std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

if your logging is done from different processes then use named mutex (winapi function: CreateMutex).

You should also be aware that locking logging might cause other problems, like some of the threads will work slower (waiting for mutex) this can cause hard to find bugs.